# Jquery Ajax - Use event within an ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any clues, how I would get this to work?

```
$( "#search_form" ).on('submit',function(event) {


ajax(function(response){
    if (response.status == 'error'){
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(response.status,response.msg);
    }else if(response.status == 'ok'){
      alert(response.status,response.msg);
    }
  });
});
```

event.preventDefault(); is not being called, probably because it's out of scope in the ajax function.
This line simply prevents the button from carrying out a post action.
How would i insert it into the ajax function? I'm just learning about callbacks and this has thrown me

Thanks y'all

Comment: Prevent it immediately, then initiate the submit on success via `$( "#search_form" )[0].submit()`

Comment: @LGSon Doing so avoids the need to unbind, as it bypasses all bound events.

Comment: No. `.click` for example will trigger events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click vs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Updated, asking how-to after the Ajax call returns, which I initially didn't understood were asked for.*

With your posted code, and as the Ajax call is async, the *submit* function will exit before the Ajax call returns, and then, when the Ajax call returns, the *event* is no longer available in that context.

---

To be able to actually resubmit the *form* after a successful Ajax call, do something like this, where you unbind the handler before submitting the 2nd time, e.g.

*Note, as of ver. 3, the [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is deprecated, so I used [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)*

```js
$("#search_form").on('submit', function(event) {

  console.log("here we enter only once")

  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("simulate async with setTimeout, and after\nits delay (3 sec.) my answer will show up")

  // simulate ajax async call
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("success ... now we submit the form properly");
      // unbind and resubmit
      $( "#search_form" ).off('submit').submit()  
  }, 3000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306380/2827823" method="post" id="search_form">
  <input type="text" value="some dummy value">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok. I understand.... Your edit would prevent submit for any result of the ajax. How would i go about submitting the form when the response.status == ok ??

Comment: $('#search_form').submit() //but flag your form so it does not go again in your handler :-)

Comment: @Leo505 You can simply submit the form again, using e.g. `$('#search_form').submit()`, and with a variable, or similar, determine if you are good to really submit it.

Comment: @Kapsonfire - I implemented this submit method and unbinding the event to prevent the loop with:  $('#search_form').off().submit(); Now i'm getting no submission of the form..

Comment: Ok, I realised why it is not sending, because the submit function is called again, which has preventDef in its first line. Will keep looking for a solution. Thanks

Comment: either unbind // .off('submit'); // if you'll never need the handler again OR set a flag, maybe with a global var (outside your handler function)

Comment: @Leo505 Added two new samples based on your comments

Comment: Sample 1 - The page would not submit after successful ajax call

success: function () {
$( "#search_form" ).off('submit').submit()  
}

Sample 2. Will not account for the user pressing Enter once value has been entered into the text box.

The method i got to work was creating a brand new form after successful ajax call and submit that.

Comment: @Leo505 Sample 2...agree, and removed. Sample 1...well, as you can see in my above sample it works just fine.

Comment: @LGSon - Yup. I agree. Your answer works and there is no reason why it should not work for me. But it does not. I have seen across a few other submissions that some people are having the same problem. They resorted to async: false. I resorted to the dirty, new form creation and submission. Thank a lot for your help.

Comment: @Leo505 Please, if you want, provide a e.g. fiddle of your non-working version of the above code sample, and I'll have a look.